# Displaying ggplot2 graphs from R in Jupyter

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I create a plot in Jupyter using the `ggplot2` R package, I get a link to the chart that says "View PDF" instead of the chart being presented inline.

I know that traditionally in IPython Notebook you were able to show the charts inline using the `%matplotlib` magic function. Does Jupyter have something similar for R and ggplot2?

What do I need to do to show the graph inline versus as a link to a PDF?

Comment: It may help to offer some example code and the output you get- are you using the `python` or the `R` kernel?

Answer (score 5):

You can show the graphs inline with this option.

```
options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')
```

You can also produce pdf files as you would regularly in R, e.g.

```
pdf("test.pdf")
ggplot(data.frame(a=rnorm(100,1,10)),aes(a))+geom_histogram()
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are currently some issues with producing ggplot2 outputs using the IRkermel. There is an open issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/145) about it. The only workaround at the moment appears to be using PDF, jpg, png outputs for your plots.

Comment: How does one create jpg output? By default my R only creates pdfs which I have to open in a new tab

Comment: Note that this issue should be fixed in current head, so you should get a svg/png output per default.