# displaying ggplot graphs in jupyter notebook

Tags: r, ggplot2, jupyter-notebook

Using Jupyter Notebook to do R in Windows 10. Although I much prefer RStudio, for reasons not worth getting into, I cannot use it. I moved a notebook I made on RStudio from my personal computer to my work computer and was not able to generate the same graphs inline on jupyter. I could save them fine onto the disk though.

Anyone know why it's not working? This is similar to 
[r graphs in jupyter - unable to start png() device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944878/r-graphs-in-jupyter-unable-to-start-png-device)
[Displaying ggplot2 graphs from R in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920380/displaying-ggplot2-graphs-from-r-in-jupyter#32708505)

But not exactly. Anyone know why I am unable to get graphs to show? I discovered that if I restart the Rkernel I can get one graph to show but not more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why it was complaining but after looking at what other graphing packages suggest, I found that I needed to install pandoc and restart jupyter.

You can install pandoc from here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.16.0.2